# Dynamically generated WebUser Control

Tags: asp.net

I have two WebUser Controls which are dynamically added to the Webform a number of times according to the user input from a previous page. There are some textboxes and drop downs in the WebUser control. I need to get the values from the textboxes of the WebUsercontrol which are added dynamically. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You should expose the control values as properties in your user control. Then you can loop through the container's Controls collection.

```
foreach (Control ctl in container.Controls)
{
    if (ctl is MyUserControl)
    {
         MyUserControl uctl = (MyUserControl)ctl;
         // do something with uctl properties, e.g.
         string myString = uctl.Address1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's just an example of a possible textbox value that you could expose as a property.

Answer (score 0):

Some psuedocode:

```
Let the parent container control be ParentContainerControl

For Each ctl` In ParentContainerControl.Controls

    If ctl is a TextBox
        Use ctr.Text
    End If

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

casting to User control Type as far as i know only works in Web Application Project, 
so you are left with some other options
- create a session or viewstate value and shared it amongst these controls.
- create a base class that both these user controls inherit from, and in the base calass you can define your properties that the controls should interact through.
-create an Interface , where both these user controls will implement.

hope this helps.